# Подключеный php файл не видит $_POST и $_SESSION

Tags: php, jquery

Нужно было сделать загрузку нескольких изображений на сервер, все сделал, но была проблема: пока файлы отправлялись и редактировались, не подгружался футер, я хотел это исправить, добавив

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upload").load("up.php");
});
```

up.php это обработчик формы, который работает, но почему-то не видет $_POST и $_SESSION

Comment: В `up.php` есть `session_start()`? И вроде `$_POST` он не должен видеть, т.к. Вы его не отправляете ему.

Comment: спасибо, session_start() там не было

Comment: вам нужно не обработчик подключать когда загрузится страница, а запрещать отправку формы пока страница не загрузилась